# Can I use python3.4 modules in python3.6?

Tags: python, module, centos, compatibility

Is it possible to run python3.4 modules in python3.6? I'm not looking for installing the python3.6 equivalent package.
Example: `yum install python34-apsw` and then in python3.6 to be able to do `import apsw`?

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: @AMC on centos7 I can only find python34-apsw.x86_64, there is no apsw for python3.6 . Can't use pip for this project

Comment: _I can only find_ Find where? _Can’t use pip for this project_ Huh, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If modules that are used in your module(apsw as ı said) is not deleted in python 3.6, you can use. Generally, python doesn't delete important modules in new versions. But ıf python34-apsw excluded in new versions of python, you may got trouble. Best way to understand is try!